Need help with FM radio circuit
I've started designing and making my own FM radio receiver based on a circuit I found on this book called Radio Receivers, from Crystal Set to Stereo
However there are some issues I have with the circuit:

The inductors that the book tells you to wrap don't correspond with the values on the circuit diagram. When I calculated them they came to be nearly 1/100th of the values given (i.e the 22uH inductor would actually only have 0.237uH of inductance)

C3 and R1 are given in ranges of 5-100nf and 10k-22k respectively. The passage below in the book does not provide any detail on how the exact values are to be decided on


Could anyone explain what could be going on here?


Show us your calculations!

But there are no instructons for winding the 22uH coil so you just need a 22 uH coil. Which coils you are talking about?

Simply, you do not have an FM receiver circuit. Your detector circuit is substandard and unlikely to be used by anyone, including you.

@Transistor I used an online calculator but plugging in the values given for the HFC into L=(u*N^2*A)/l should give you the same values

@Dereck Yeah I'm new to rf/radio electronics and I just wanted to just build a circuit I could experiment with. GreatScott did a video making another much simpler FM circuit using this book so I thought It was a good source. I might just look for another design I could build from instead.

@Justme It's the one on the left. The one that is not tapped is meant to be the 22uH coil.

The shown receiver really is not designed. It's a version of super-regenerative detector plus an audio amplifier which contains one transistor and LM386 IC. Not designed??? - that's true only for the JFET stage which is the super-regenerative detector.
Super-regenerative detector is actually a R.F. oscillator which runs at the receiving frequency. As an oscillator it's bad. It rectifies (in a P-N junction) its own R.F. signal and the resulted DC moves the DC bias point of the JFET. The oscillation is choked due the gain reduction caused by the change of the  bias point. But the oscillation starts soon again when the rectified DC decays in resistances. The oscillation starts and stops typically tens of thousands of times per a second. For a hobbyist it's no problem to get an oscillator to behave in that way, when he tries to build a continuous wave stable sine wave oscillator by following only experimenter's intuition without obeying any well known trusted design. That's why I said it's not designed. The "quenching" appears without asking. Of course, an ultra-competent electronics designer can mathematically optimize the operation, but it's beyond the capabilities of me and very likely also most of the other hobbyists.
How a bad oscillator which starts and stops without asking can be a detector in a radio receiver? That's because the existence of an external R.F. signal at the right frequency greatly accelerates the restarting of the oscillation. The stronger the external signal, the faster the oscillation starts. If one measures the DC voltages in the circuit he can see that the DC voltages follow (maybe only millivolts, but follow) the variations of the strength of the external R.F. signal. That's essentially AM demodulation.
Inventor and engineer Edwin Armstrong interested in the effect about 100 years ago and developed soon a radio receiver which uses it. As is it's an AM detector, but it detects also FM if it's intentionally tuned just a little off from the exact FM station frequency. Before the FM detection could happen Armstrong had also to invent a practical wide band FM radio transmitter.
During WW2 super-regenerative radios were widely used in tactical level (=front line) communication. The simplicity of the circuit made the radios reliable and the same oscillator tube could be used as a few hundred mW transmitter. Typical operating frequency was 30...50 MHz.A walkie-talkie could be constructed of only 2 vacuum tubes (=double pentodes). Probably millions of super-regenerative receivers were used in proximity radar detonators in the ammunition of heavy anti-aircraft cannons.
The coils are not critical. The center tapped one should be good for resonant circuit in the wanted operating frequency, probably L= something around 100 nanohenries. The rightmost is needed to make a low pass filter which allows the DC current of the JFET to go on, but reduces the R.F. component so much that the audio amp transistor is not saturated by the R.F. signal. I have tried quite the same coil as shown in the drawing (with no idea of the actual inductance) and it worked.
The problematic parts R1 and C3 need some experimenting. They both affect how well the quenching and the restarting of the oscillation happen. Try at first quite small C3, say 4,7 nF and let R1 be a 10k or 22k trimpot, adjust  to find the best quenching & restarting. It appears as high noise if there's no R.F-signal at the oscillation frequency.
Caution: Super-regenerative detector used as the first stage of a radio receiver can badly disturb other radio receivers because the detector oscillates and essentially works as noise transmitter. But the detector is very sensitive, so it may work OK even with no antenna. Without an antenna the radius of the badly disturbed area is maybe only ten meters.

Re, "it's an AM detector, but it detects also FM if it's intentionally tuned just a little off" FYI: That's got a name. It's called slope detection.

Thanks for the reply, I unfortunately might just look for another base circuit to go from seeing how unreliable this design is. I'm very new to rf/radio circuits and so I might try something a bit simpler or at least a more proven design.

The area of interest seems to be the components involved in pushing this VHF oscillator into squegging, otherwise known as super-regeneration.

The inductors that the book tells you to wrap don't correspond with
the values on the circuit diagram. When I calculated them they came to
be nearly 1/100th of the values given (i.e the 22uH inductor would
actually only have 0.237uH of inductance)

The 22uH coil in question is labelled VFP while the coil described in the box is labelled HFC. As the OP has suggested, the inductance of these two don't jive.
In many super-regens I've observed in the wild, this inductor is usually a molded choke whose value is a few microhenries. It should mostly isolate the oscillations at ~100 MHz from the RC components following.
In an effort to determine an optimum value, a LTspice simulation was run. Be aware that simple spice simulations of VHF oscillators often give a vague impression of even carefully-built breadboard oscillators. Nevertheless, spice gives a starting point.

A small number of default LTspice JFETs were tried - some refused even to oscillate. High-gain JFETs did best, as did those with higher IDSS, like J310.
A wide range of choking inductor values were tried between 1uH and 22uH. All did their isolating job, allowing super-regeneration. In my crude simulation, values below 0.3uH failed to quench oscillation (failed super-regeneration). A value of 4.7uH seemed near optimum.



C3 and R1 are given in ranges of 5-100nf and 10k-22k respectively. The
passage below in the book does not provide any detail on how the exact
values are to be decided on

R1 likely has a range of 10k-22k to accommodate JFETs having different characteristics. JFETs are notorious for having pinch-off voltage and IDSS values spanning a wide range. In my LTSpice simulation, high values of R1 caused JFET channel current to be too small for robust oscillations required for regeneration. A value of 10k for R1 seemed appropriate for those JFETs that actually oscillated.
C3 in combination with R1 sets the super-regeneration rate. In an FM broadcast-band radio, one would not want this super-regeneration frequency to lie within the audio band - it should be significantly-above 20kHz. One might think of this super-regeneration system as a Pulse-Width-modulator (PWM) whose regeneration frequency depends on log(carrier-amplitude).
Super-regeneration frequency of say, 30kHz is still very close to the upper audio limit of broadcast-band FM modulation. One wonders what the following LM386 power amplifier is seeing as input: audio, or PWM?

If you care to fool around with a LTSPICE super-regen simulation, find below a circuit similar to OP's. The FM antenna is loosely simulated by a voltage source having a feeble 2pf capacitance (C6). On a breadboard, this should be a short wire no more than 20 cm.
The following audio stage is loosely simulated by a 1k resistor.
Note that component designations don't correspond to OP's schematic designations, which are un-readably tiny.

Once again, don't expect this simulation to mimic reality - construction of VHF oscillators is somewhat difficult, and super-regens even moreso.
Be aware that super-regens can only be simulated as TRANSient runs, since so much of their operating envelope is non-linear. Nevertheless, this simulation demonstrates well that super-regens are really wonderful log-amplitude detectors. Note that amplitude of V2 varies in a logarithmic sequence. PWM output frequency seems a near-linear progression:

That's an enviably fine simulation!

Thank you for the detailed response! I will certainly try and use LTspice seeing how useful the simulations can be. Though I might just have to greatly change this or just use another base circuit, because honestly I'm a bit too inexperienced to try and make this work.
